# Why is this formula for divergence in an orthonormal basis incorrect?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvilinear-coordinates

Lets say we have variables $h_1 , h_2 , ... h_n$ that depend on our usual coordinates $x_1 , x_2 .... x_n$ in Euclidian space, and basis vectors $\hat{w_1}, \hat{w_2} ... \hat{w_n}$ such that for the position vector $\vec{X}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j e_j =\sum_{j=1}^{n} h_j |w_j| \hat{w_j}$ (the reason for the $|w_j|$ is just to make the basis elements have unit magnitude, sorry if its a little gross). We take the $\hat{w}$'s to be an orthonormal basis.

Lets say we have a vector field $\vec{V}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} f_j(\vec{X})e_j =\sum_{j=1}^{n}g_j(\vec{X})\hat{w_j}$, we'd compute the divergence as $\nabla \cdot \vec{V} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}  \frac{\partial\vec{V} \cdot e_j}{\partial x_j}$. Though we typically use the euclidian components when computing divergence it seems like there shouldn't be a problem with converting this expression to another coordinate system.

To get this in a better form we first look at $\vec{V} \cdot e_k=\sum_{j=1}^{n}g_j(\vec{X})\hat{w_j} \cdot e_k$. From our definitions we also see $\hat{w_j}=\frac{1}{|w_j|} \frac{\partial\vec{X}}{\partial h_j}$ so $\hat{w_j} \cdot e_k=\frac{1}{|w_j|}\frac{\partial\vec{X} \cdot e_k}{\partial h_j}=\frac{1}{|w_j|}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial h_j}$ so
$\vec{V} \cdot e_k=\sum_{j=1}^{n}g_j(\vec{X})\frac{1}{|w_j|}\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial h_j}$
Returning to the divergence, $\nabla \cdot \vec{V} = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}  \frac{\partial g_i(\vec{X}) \frac{1}{|w_i|}\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial h_i}}{\partial x_j}$. With the commutativity of partial derivatives we should have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial h_i}=0$, leaving us with $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}  \frac{\partial g_i(\vec{X}) \frac{1}{|w_i|}}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial h_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}  \frac{\partial g_i(\vec{X}) \frac{1}{|w_i|}}{\partial h_i}$, clearly not correct. The right answer should look like $\sum_{i=1}^{3} \frac{1}{|w_1||w_2||2_3|} \frac{\partial g_i(\vec{X}) \frac{|w_1||w_2||2_3|}{|w_i|}}{\partial h_i}$ in the case n=3, with the more general case following a similar form. From what I can tell these are not equivalent.I can't figure out what is wrong here--any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Be careful what you are holding constant in the partial derivatives!  $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial h_i}$ is not $0$.

Comment: @user10354138 I was suspecting that was too good to be true. I dont understand why though, can't you switch the order of both, making the inside either 0 or 1, resulting in 0?

Comment: you can only swap when both come from the same coordinate system, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ commutes with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$. Likewise, $\frac{\partial}{\partial h^{\alpha}}$ commutes with $\frac{\partial}{\partial h^{\beta}}$. But, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ in general doesn’t commute with $\frac{\partial}{\partial h^{\alpha}}$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4496385/568204) for more explicit explanation.

Comment: No you can't switch the order.  The symmetry of partial derivatives only work when you have the same coordinate frame.  Think the 1-dimensional example: $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}x}=1$ so if you differentiate that wrt $x^{-1}$ again you get $0$, but you have $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}(x^{-1})}=-x^2$ so $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}(x^{-1})})=-2x\neq 0$.

Comment: @user10354138 wow I guess I really was mislead. Im assuming by coordinate frame you're referring to (in the euclidian example) (x1, x2... x_n). Im definitely going to try to rework this. Thanks for the insight

Comment: @user10354138 I've been trying to find a way to work around this but it seems like its not going to lead anywhere. I know how to derive the formula in 3 dimensions through using the fact that we can make the coordinate system right handed and using some vector calc identities but I am assuming there is a more elegant/straightforward way to get the result--do you happen to know any such approach? thanks a lot

Comment: You could do it with the chain rule expressing $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ in terms of the $\frac{\partial}{\partial h_k}$s etc.  On the other hand, the best way is to use Riemannian geometry, and there are a few questions on this site including the various equivalent definition of divergence.  It is very straightforward (almost a one-liner) to use, e.g., the Lie derivative of volume form version and get your formula.